# Why does this program gives no output for float and double datatypes?

Tags: c

Why does this program gives no output for float and double datatypes. However, what will be the result when the same code is replaced with for loop??

```
      # include <stdio.h>

      int main()
      {
       float x=1.1;                    
       while (x==1.1)
       {  
        printf("%f\n",x);
        x=x-0.1;
       }
       return 0;
      }
```

Comment: Do you understand that 1.1 cannot be exactly represented?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: There are many duplicates, use either `double x` or `1.1f` because a plain `1.1` has a type of `double`.

Comment: By the way, you compare a `float` with a `double` in the loop.

Comment: There's gotta be like 100 duplicates for this...

Answer (score 7):

```
   float x=1.1;                    
   while (x==1.1)
```

float and double variables are not capable of storing the exact value of 1.1, only a very close approximation. The exact value in a float and a double will be slightly different due to the difference in precision.

1.1 is a *double* value. You are storing 1.1 as a double into a float which will slightly alter the value. Then you compare it with the double value 1.1 so it will not quite be equal and so will never enter your condition.

For this to work you need to write 1.1f to ensure that you are working with the same data type everywhere. 
In addition I'm sure someone else will explain why comparing floating point values for exact equality is often a bad idea.